# How to change the directory name for CTAGS (/tags)

Tags: ctags

My codebase uses a directory at the root of the project called `tags/` already. How do I go about using a different directory to store the contents of CTAG (ex. `/.ctags`)?

Answer (score 0):

To quote the ctags manpage (`man 1 ctags`):

```
-f tagfile
            Use the name specified by tagfile for the  tag  file
             [...]  Ctags will stubbornly refuse to take orders if tagfile ex‐
            ists and its first line contains something other than a valid tags
            line.
```

For example

```
ctags -f .mytags src/*.c
```

will create a file called `.mytags` in the current directory as tag file containing tags for all `.c` files in `src`.

To put it in a subdirectory just provide the filename with the path:

```
ctags -f ./.mytags/tags src/*.c
```

---

`.ctags` is the default configuration file for ctags - do not use this name for your tag file.